# What is "narrow" mean as in "Narrow Decision"?

Tags: word-meaning

[In Narrow Decision, Supreme Court Sides With Baker Who Turned Away Gay Couple](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/04/us/politics/supreme-court-sides-with-baker-who-turned-away-gay-couple.html)

> The court’s decision was **narrow**, and it left open the larger question
>   of whether a business can discriminate against gay men and lesbians
>   based on rights protected by the First Amendment.

I think it maybe means the article of the decision being very short.
Or maybe means the narrow-minded.

Comment: "A narrow result is one that could easily have been different because the amount by which someone failed or succeeded was very small" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/narrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a *narrow* decision means the judges ruled by a narrow majority, like 5-4.  However, in this case narrow refers instead to the *scope* of the decision, specifically targeted against what the court determined was discrimination by a government official.

The SCOTUS decision means that government agency's action is now invalid, but only because their reasons for the action violated the U.S. Constitution.  It does not address the constitutionality of the underlying issue, so it only affects a very *narrow* set of circumstances.

From the article:

> “The court reversed the Masterpiece Cakeshop decision **based on concerns unique to the case** but reaffirmed its longstanding rule that states can prevent the harms of discrimination in the marketplace, including against L.G.B.T. people,” said Louise Melling, the group’s deputy legal director.

It is unlikely that a New York Times news article would call any decision or person "narrow-minded", since the [Journalist's Code of Ethics](https://www.spj.org/ethicscode.asp), among other things, requires that journalists, "Seek truth and report it", and, "Support the open and civil exchange of views, even views they find repugnant."

Such subjective statements would be acceptable in the *Opinion / Editorial* section, however.